# How do I extend this regex to match www.example.com in addition to http://example.com?

Tags: javascript, regex

I've got a regex for detecting links that works pretty well for urls of the form http://example.com, http://www.example.com etc but not for www.example.com

I am trying to extend what i have so that www.foo.com also gets matched without breaking previous functionality.

I tried this:

```
/\(?\b((http|https|ftp):\/\/|)(www\.)[-A-Za-z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_()|!:,.;]*[-A-Za-z0-9+&@#\/%=~_()|]/
```

but this only works when www is present and  doesn't work e.g. for http://example.com ...

Comment: See [RFC2606](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2606)

Answer (score 1):

I believe I've resolved this.

I need to make *both* the http and wee blocks optional AND i have to modify the regex to detect only things that end in .com/.net etc so that i dont just match strings if http and www are both optional

here's the regex that works:

```
 /\(?\b((http|https):\/\/)?(www\.)?[-A-Za-z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_()|!:,.;]*\.(com|net|co)\/?[-A-Za-z0-9+&@#\/%=~_()|]*/gi;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to make the www optional like so:

```
/\(?\b((http|https|ftp):\/\/|)(www\.)?[-A-Za-z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_()|!:,.;]*[-A-Za-z0-9+&@#\/%=~_()|]/
```

by adding the "?" after the (www.) group you can make it optional